# Uncaught TypeError When Trying to get Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to learn to use Chartjs and I am running into an issue when I am trying to grab the canvas element by its ID. For some reason it is not being defined. Is this because I am calling `document.getElementByID` and the this is not being run within the HTML file? I was trying to use an external file to host all of my JS as opposed to cluttering my HTML file.

Error Message:
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Found at line 2 in charts-option.js: `var ctx = document.getElementByID("sessions-graph").getContext("2d");`

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Google Super Proxy Test</title>
        <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="chart-options.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

    <div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="sessions-graph" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

chart-options.js

```
// Get the context of the canvas element
var ctx = document.getElementByID("sessions-graph").getContext("2d");
var sessionsGraph = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data); //Create a chart with "data" array

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};


Chart.defaults.global = {

    //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
    scaleBeginAtZero : true,

    //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines : true,

    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
    barShowStroke : true,

    //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
    barStrokeWidth : 2,

    //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
    barValueSpacing : 5,

    //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
    barDatasetSpacing : 1

}
```

Comment: In addition to the typo, you're trying to refer an element in `body`, which doesn't exist yet. Wrap the script in `window.onload` or move the `<script>` tag to the `body` _after_ `#sessions-graph`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a typo, the method should be `document.getElementById()`

Comment: How about timing? Does `#sessions-graph` exist at the time it's referred?

Comment: @Lee great catch, but now it's showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`. Seems that it isn't finding the canvas element. Any ideas?

Comment: @Teemu great question. It could be that my JS is running before the canvas is called

Comment: Move the scripts to before the closing body tag, should fix that.

Comment: Yep. Thank you @Lee & @Teemu. by wrapping everything in `window.onload = function(){...}`